# pattern recognition using neural network in matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am doing a project in character recognition of a local language. I created the dataset. But I am not sure how to feed it using neural network?

[image: Training step]

In this stage, I can only select one image as input rather than whole set of same character. How to proceed?

Pls help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know these neurons don't understand 2d input, so you need to make a 1d array from image:

```
image1flat = image1(:);
image2flat = image2(:);
```

Then put them into a 2d trainning set array (note that "Samples are:" option on your picture)

```
%samples are columns now
trainningSet = [image1flat image2flat];
```

Automated code:

```
%change this to folder where the files are
cd('/path/to/files');
%change this to your file format
files = dir('*.png');
result = [];
for i = 1:length(files)
    A{i} = imread(files(i).name);
    Aflat{i} = A{i}(:);
    result = [result Aflat{i}];
end
%put the result into nprtool
```

Comment: Do we need to code ? Can we use **nprtool** GUI tool available in Neural network module?

Comment: If you want to load an image using matlab, type `image1 = imread('filename.xxx');` or drag-n-drop it to workspace, after that matlab will ask you about the name of the variable

Comment: figured out that :)
Should the input.mat and target.mat need to be same?